# Write properties from a grails message.properties file

Tags: grails

How would I write a property from a grails i18n message.properties file to a html data attribute.
I tried this but it gives me a string value of 'CardProps.nullable' and not the actual property value.

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX" class="card" id="card-number" name="number" data-required-message='<g:message code="CardProps.nullable"/>' >
```

also tried this.

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX" class="card" id="card-number" name="number" data-required-message="${message(code: 'CardProps.nullable')}" >
```

Anyone any ideas how to get the message value and not the string 'CardProps.nullable' in my data attribute.

Comment: What you have should be correct (both forms), are you sure you have 'CardProps.nullable' in your message.properties file?

Comment: For some reason I had to restart my grails app for it to take effect. Working now thanks. I hate when it's as stupid as that.

Comment: yeah, i find `exit, grails run-app` is often the solution to the many problems i've encountered.

Comment: Yep me too, unfortunately I haven't learnt to do it before I write on stackoverflow and look stupid :)